# ARC not working in iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I converted my project to using ARC and i works fine in iOS 5. But when running on the 4.3 simulator, i get a lot of these messages:

> 2011-10-16 12:23:29.915 iRoster[1604:1300b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5176e60 of class EKCalendar autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

I guess I could put a lot of    @autoreleasepool around, but I had the impression that was optional. And the strange thing is that it only appears when running on 4.3

What should I do?

EDIT:
I have now placed some @autoreleasepool around and that reduced the messages a lot, so that seems to be the case.

Comment: Was there an `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` statement there before? Not the one in the `main()` function, but another that you created yourself.

Comment: Yes, I removed it when converting to ARC. Do you think there may be some residues after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own autorelease pools within your application logic that you manage yourself pre-ARC, you need to replace them with `@autoreleasepool` constructs, and the compiler will deal with them accordingly.

Converting to ARC doesn't necessarily mean your existing autorelease pools are no longer needed — you'll still need individual pools to contain temporary autoreleased objects in, for example, loops in other threads, so they won't spend forever in memory and/or start leaking in those threads. See [this Apple documentation on using autorelease pools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).